# After closing alpine modal from blade layout, components can't be clicked

Tags: modal-dialog, laravel-blade, alpine.js

What I'm trying to do is having the modal activator from the navbar in a blade layout and making it appear on the main content, however when I click the button from the navbar and closes the modal by clicking outside the modal, I can't click anything on the screen thus I have to refresh. I tried adding a close button but after it closes once then i try to open again, it closes quickly on the first and second try, then only the backdrop remains on the third try.

ps: new to posting here

To open the modal from another layout

```
<li @click="modelOpen =!modelOpen">Grooming Packages</li>
```

Modal

```
<body x-data="{ modelOpen: false }">
@include('layouts/navigation')

<div class="fixed inset-0 z-50 overflow-y-auto" aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" x-show="modelOpen">
  <div class="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen px-4 text-center md:items-center sm:block sm:p-0">
    <div x-cloak @click="modelOpen = false" x-show="modelOpen" class="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true"></div>
    <div x-cloak x-show="modelOpen" x-data="{selected:1}" class="inline-block"> 
      Content 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Only means of closing the modal is by clicking outside the modal, i prefer it that way

Comment: Could you include a little bit more context? How do you open the modal? You don't use `modelOpen` at the example at the moment. Where is the modal located inside the page structure?